# What is the Meaning of "Posetal shadow?"

Tags: category-theory, order-theory

[Here](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/11/11/11-11.pdf) on the 4th page,
what does the term **posetal shadow** mean ?

Comment: There is no forth page.  The pages begin at 252.

Comment: @WilliamElliot So 254 the last paragraph. I meant 4th in the sense of pdf viewer in Firefox. Just search within the pdf for "shadow".

Comment: This convinces me pdf files are too clumsy and awkward  to mbother with. Present only the portion of the file that is pertinent..